# NativeWindows or Win32?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

I'm a bit confused about the difference between:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWindow, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

and

```
virtual void WndProc(Message %m);
```

I know that the first is to get message to menage event in win32, but so "WndProc(Message %m)" is the same thing when we are programming a Windows Form project?

The last question is: When is better to use NativeWindow methods and when is better to use win32 methods to manage events?

My project is a simple window form with a panel, on the Panel I call a window where I can menage OpenGL operations.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The former is raw C-style Win32 API. The latter is a member of a .NET classes `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and `System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow`, as expressed in C++/CLI.

I imagine that .NET runtime internally implements `WndProc` the Win32 callback, and arranges for it to call `WndProc` the class method, if you choose to override it in your class derived from `Control`.

I'm not sure why you need `NativeWindow`. If for some reason you want to handle raw window messages, then derive your class from `Panel` and override `WndProc` there; `Panel` derives from `Control`.

Comment: Thank you Igor;
I call NativeWindow to create an OpenGL render context to display on window what I created using OpenGL library; and so to menage event I need to get window message.
But at the moment i don't know if this is the best way to do all those things;
if you know a better alternative please tell me.

Thank you

Comment: You can derive your class from `NativeWindow` and create an instance of *that*; in this class, you can override WndProc if you are so inclined. I don't know enough about .NET or OpenGL to give design advice, I must regretfully admit.